# How to auto scale helm chart statefulsets

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have installed the rabbitmq cluster using helm chart. Rabbitmq using statefulsets so is there any way to auto scale this ?

Also one more question how to auto scale (HPA) deployment having PVC ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

StatefulSets can be autoscaled with HPA:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: some-service
spec:
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
  - resource:
      name: memory
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
    type: Resource
  - resource:
      name: cpu
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
    type: Resource
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: some-service
```

Regarding PVC and StatefulSets and HPA - I'm not sure but I think that depends on reclaimPolicy of StorageClass of your PVC. Just make sure you have `reclaimPolicy: Retain` in your StorageClass definition. Having that you should preserve data on scaling events.

If you mean Deployments with HPA and PVC - it should work, but always remember that if you have multiple replicas with one shared PVC - all replicas will try to mount it. If PVC is ReadWriteMany - there should be no issues. If it is ReadWriteOnce - then all replicas will be scheduled on one node. If there is not enough resources on node to fit all replicas - you will get some pods in Pending state forever.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer so if due to memory and cpu HPA increases number of pod ...so with statefulsets if pvc attached how it work

Comment: StatefulSets are a bit different than Deployments - they can use volumeClaimTemplates. That means that each replica of StatefulSet will have its own PVC. Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#creating-a-statefulset

Comment: Thankyou I absolutely got it thanks again for writing clear and easy definition.

Comment: Is there any way to auto scale helm charts ? Like I am using rabbitmq helm chart which create 3 statefulsets pods. Each having own PVC

Comment: Yes like is there any option we can implement direct HPA on whole helm chart or anything

Comment: Helm chart is nothing more than a collection of templated Kubernetes manifests. You may include HPA manifest for StatefulSet, it's 100% possible and actually pretty easy. But you cannot scale Helm chart as a whole.

Comment: Okay got t Thankyou so much answers and helping me out

Comment: Isnt this a problem? yes you scale up the rabbitmq, but what happens when HPA decides to scale down? you will be left with unavailable nodes..